# ScriptEngine based 'javascript' makes incorrect regex validation (for IP address)

Tags: javascript, java, scriptengine, javascript-engine

Following regex gives wrong result for ip address validation rvrn though regular expression is correct and gives correct result in node based running of .js code.

```
    public static void excuteWithinEngine() throws ScriptException{

    // ip address regex
    String regEx = "^(?:\\d|1?\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])(?:\\.(?:\\d|1?\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])){3}$"; 

    Set<String> in=new HashSet<String>();
    //IPv4 A:B:C:D. if more than one chars are at position B,C then jsvascript based regex-test fails
    in.add("10.2.2.2");//output: true. (correct result)
    in.add("10.2.13.2");//output: false. (incorrect result)
    in.add("10.2.13.25");//output: false. (incorrect result)
    in.add("10.2.2.25");//output: true. (correct result)

    for(String input:in){

        String s = input;
        ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine se = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        se.put("regEx", regEx);
        se.put("string", s);
        se.eval("var RE = new RegExp(regEx);");
        boolean b= (boolean)se.eval("RE.test(string);"); // test function

        System.out.println("Testing "+s+" :"+b); 

    }
}
```

Comment: Updated details. Basically all being IP address and correct, each should have passed. But two input validation fails.

Answer (score 0):

Can you print the error log? Let me know what it says!

Also, try using the following regex:

```
var ipv4rgx = @"^((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d{1,2})(\.|$)){4}";
var ipv6rgx = "^([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}(:|$)){8}";
```

Comment: there's no error. The match will just fail with result 'false'.

Here requirement is not regex, i fail to understand why it doesn't work. Regex is correct, works fine in seperate javascript code. Then why not with script engine?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why this is happening, but it seems to be related to using the times modifier `{3}`. If you change your regular expression to

```
"^(?:\\d|1?\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])(?:\\.(?:\\d|1?\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5]))(?:\\.(?:\\d|1?\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5]))(?:\\.(?:\\d|1?\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5]))$"
```

(expanding the final `{3}` to three explicit expressions), then it seems to work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for ur time @khelwood, I have another regex that will work. Just want to root cause why this one fails?

I don’t think it’s problem with expansion (i.e. {3}). For example following regex works fine:
"^((\\d|1?\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.){3}(?:\\d|1?\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$"; //gives correct result

Comment: If I knew, I would tell you. Maybe it is a bug.